# Using 'shared_paths' function in QGIS Expression Dialog

Tags: qgis, geometry, expression

I am not a QGIS expression expert. I am trying to understand usage of `shared_paths` function. The help text doesn't help at all:

> Returns a collection containing paths shared by the two input geometries. Those going in the same direction are in the first element of the collection, those going in the opposite direction are in the second element. The paths themselves are given in the direction of the first geometry.

Example from help text:

```sql
geom_to_wkt(
  shared_paths(
    geom_from_wkt(
      'MULTILINESTRING((26 125,26 200,126 200,126 125,26 125), (51 150,101 150,76 175,51 150)))'),
    geom_from_wkt(
    'LINESTRING(151 100,126 156.25,126 125,90 161, 76 175)'
)))
```

returns

```
'GeometryCollection (MultiLineString ((126 156.25, 126 125), (101 150, 90 161), (90 161, 76 175)), MultiLineString EMPTY)'
```

What does *paths shared by the two input geometries* mean? What exactly does it return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function [`shared_paths()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#shared-paths) returns the common space two lines share - so similar to the interesection of two lines. The difference is that `shared_parths()`

- A) only works for lines and
- B) (more important) is aware of line direction. This might be useful when dealing with networks for routing etc. - e.g. if you just want to get lines that run in the same direction as one of the input lines.

Consider this screenshot: you have two lines, line1 (black) and line2 (red). `shared_paths()` returns the blue line - the space that both lines share:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So you say it is possible to get the same result by applying `intersection`  to two lines if their segments overlap?